# How to get a specific German bibliography in LaTeX

Tags: bibliographies, natbib, german

for my master thesis I need a specific format for citations and the layout of the bibliography. I was wondering if anyone can help me to do that with LaTex:

This is how cites should look like. The cites have to be in a footnote. After 3 authors there should be "u.a." instead of "et. al". The year of the citation should be in braces after the author names. If there are similar keys for the same literatur the keys should be individually labeled with an additional a, b, c and so on:

```
Vgl. Booth, Colomb, Williams (1995), S. 15.
Vgl. Aladwani (2002a), S. 339-340.
Vgl. Aladwani (2002b), S. 190-191.
```

This is how the bibliopgraphy should look like:

```
Stelzer u. a. (1996)
   Dirk Stelzer, Uwe Müller, Michael Kunz, Werner Mellis:
   Softwareprozeßverbesserung durch organisatorisches Lernen. Studien zur
   Systementwicklung des Lehrstuhls für Wirtschaftsinformatik der Universität
   zu Köln. Band 10. Köln 1996
```

So first there should be the cites key as used in the cites above. Afterwards the complete citation should be listet indented above. This is the structure of the indented complete citation:

Surname and lastname of the authors or edtiors (with an additional "(Hrsg.)"). Then a ":". Then the title. Edition. Place of publication (or "o.O" if not availbale) and year of publication (or "o.J". if not available).

If I use this commands the text cites are looking fine so far but the bibliography is not right:

```
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{natbib}
(...)
\bibliographystyle{dinat}
\bibliography{literatur}
```

I appreciate any help and thanks in adavance!

Comment: Try `latex makebst` in terminal window (cmd.exe in Windows OS). This is provided by package `custom-bib`, and all you have to do is giving your keys to the questions it displays.

Comment: Another possibility would be `biblatex`. But as it stands, the question is the kind of *give me codez*. Modifying a whole bibliography style is a very very time-consuming effort, even more with the `bst`-system.